# How to to get some of my apm data to ROS for doing 3D SLAM using MAVROS

Tags: mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

THIS is what it shows when i launch apm2.launch file.

Built-in SIMD instructions: SSE, SSE2

Built-in MAVLink package version: 2016.4.4

[ INFO]  Built-in MAVLink dialect: ardupilotmega

[ INFO]  MAVROS started. MY ID 1.240, TARGET ID 1.1

[ERROR]  FCU: Calibrating barometer

[ INFO] CON: Got HEARTBEAT, connected. FCU: ArduPilotMega

[ERROR] FCU: barometer calibration complete

[ERROR] FCU: GROUND START

[ WARN]  VER: broadcast request timeout, retries left 4

[ WARN]  VER: broadcast request timeout, retries left 3

[ WARN]  VER: unicast request timeout, retries left 2

[ WARN] VER: unicast request timeout, retries left 1

[ WARN] VER: unicast request timeout, retries left 0

[ WARN] VER: your FCU don't support AUTOPILOT_VERSION, switched to default capabilities

[ERROR] FCU: ArduCopter V3.2.1 (36b405fb)

[ERROR] FCU: Frame: QUAD

[ INFO] WP: mission received

[ INFO] PR: parameters list received

and these are the topics published

/diagnostics

/mavlink/from

/mavlink/to

/mavros/altitude

/mavros/battery

/mavros/cam_imu_sync/cam_imu_stamp

/mavros/extended_state

/mavros/global_position/compass_hdg

/mavros/global_position/global

/mavros/global_position/local

/mavros/global_position/raw/fix

/mavros/global_position/raw/gps_vel

/mavros/global_position/rel_alt

/mavros/imu/atm_pressure

/mavros/imu/data

/mavros/imu/data_raw

/mavros/imu/mag

/mavros/imu/temperature

/mavros/local_position/odom

/mavros/local_position/pose

/mavros/local_position/velocity

/mavros/manual_control/control

/mavros/mission/waypoints

/mavros/radio_status

/mavros/rc/in

/mavros/rc/out

/mavros/rc/override

/mavros/setpoint_accel/accel

/mavros/setpoint_position/local

/mavros/setpoint_raw/attitude

/mavros/setpoint_raw/global

/mavros/setpoint_raw/local

/mavros/setpoint_raw/target_attitude

/mavros/setpoint_raw/target_global

/mavros/setpoint_raw/target_local

/mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel

/mavros/state

/mavros/time_reference

/mavros/vfr_hud

/mavros/wind_estimation

/rosout

/rosout_agg

/tf

/tf_static

i do /diagnostics and came to know that its because of the absence of GPS and other compulsory hardware. BUT i do not want to use GPS and compass data

THANKS in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233334/hi-everyone,-i-want-to-get-some-of-my-apm-data-to-ros-for-doing-3d-slam.-for-that-i-am-using-mavros.-i-successfully-installed-the-mavros-but-when-i-echo-my-topics,-some-of-them-publish-data-but-others-not./) by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2016-04-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MhAyman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23522/mhayman/) on 2016-06-13**:
@hashim have you come into any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosservice call /mavros/set_stream_rate 0 10 1

use the above command to start publishing other datas as well

---

Originally posted by [hashim](https://answers.ros.org/users/23778/hashim/) with karma: 53 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0